# AWS .NET no way to tell if an object has been successfully deleted

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

tI was trying to research this but I can't seem to find an answer. In .NET (VB.NET) I have the following code to delete an object in Amazon S3:

```
client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, RegionEndpoint.USEast1)
    Dim request As DeleteObjectRequest = New DeleteObjectRequest
    With request
        .BucketName = bucketName
        .Key = keyToDelete
    End With
    Try
        Dim resp As DeleteObjectResponse = client.DeleteObject(request)
        Dim headers As WebHeaderCollection = resp.Headers
        For Each key As String In headers.Keys
            Return "Response Header: " + key + "Value: " + headers.Get(key)
        Next
    Catch ex As AmazonS3Exception
        Return "Not Deleted"
    End Try
    Return "Deleted"
```

What I can't figure out is how do I know that the object was successfully deleted? I thought it would throw an exception, but it doesn't. I can pass whatever key I want, that doesn't exist, and it still works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this thread, https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=60081, unless the function throws an exception, the object was successfully deleted. However, the documentation, http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3_DeleteObject.htm, does confirm the behavior you see where it will return successfully if the object does not exist. I guess the theory is that an object that doesn't exist is deleted.

You may have to check to see if the object exists before trying to delete. This thread, https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=219046, gives a couple methods. If the object does exist, then a failed delete should throw an exception.

Comment: Hmm, I guess that logic (An object that doesn't exist is deleted) makes sense though, perhaps I'll leave it as is then, Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, `System.IO.File.Delete` won't throw an exception either if the file doesn't exist. The consistent behavior makes sense.